# Download Flash video file from any video site?

Tags: download, flv

I know there are plenty of ways to download [Flash video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) files (.flv) from the video sites like [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube), etc. But if the site changes the procedure of download, most of the time, it will break.

Is there any generic way to download without depending on a particular site/software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HTTP sniffer to grab the URL of the FLV file that the Flash Video player calls. I've outlined it here: https://superuser.com/questions/28241/where-to-find-a-youtube-hd-video-downloader-bookmarklet-google-chrome/28537#28537

Comment: I am using Firebug to trace all XMLHTTPRequest calls to the server and able to filter out the actual file.

Answer (score 3):

Use Firefox with this fantastic add-on: [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/). It works for me on almost all the sites I go to.

[image]

Comment: Argh! Not the JPEG!!!

Comment: @joshhunt : dude... you need to surf the web with lynx. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[TubeMaster++](http://www.tubemaster.net/index.html).

I made an animated GIF for you to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: I just lost about 30 minutes of my battery life watching this. :)

Comment: LOL Sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

Look for screen recorder software, and however a video is playing you can capture it :p (this is universal for sure.)

**[EDIT]**

If you are using Firefox type **about:cache** in the address bar and you will get a list of all the files you have seen in the browser (the cache, like John_T say.)

Comment: **without depending on a particular site/ software**

Comment: humm , okay ...

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser cache, no matter how much they change, the file will usually end up there.

Comment: Here's a tool which can scan the browser cache for you and find FLV video files: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Internet Explorer, search for *.FLV in 'temporary internet files'.

With Firefox it's a bit trickier. The default cache location is:

*C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxx.default\Cache*

Now you won't find FLV files in this folder (in fact, NO file in this folder has an extension). But if you sort by size and check the date/time -stamp, you'll get a fair idea of what you're looking for. Copy the file to another location and add the extension FLV.

Answer (score 0):

There is free version of [ImTOO DVD Ripper](http://www.imtoo.com/download-youtube-video.html) and it works great.

I use [Internet Download Manger](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) addon for Firefox is even better that DownlodHelper in my opinion, because it allows setting custom downloaders like IDM (win) or Axel (linux) for different actions. Not limited to flv.

[image]